# groovy BUG! exception in phase 'canonicalization' in source unit (Groovy v 2.4.7 versus 2.4.8)

Tags: groovy

I tried updating from Groovy v 2.4.7 to 2.4.8 as this version is supposed to fix a problem with keeping the transient effective for not serializing from subclasses. After updating to 2.4.8 I get:

> Caused by: BUG! exception in phase 'canonicalization' in source unit 'C:\Dev\Perseus\ContentManagement\core\src\main\groovy\com\agenabio\content\Content.groovy' unexpected NullpointerException
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:174)

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: It would help to share Content.groovy, or make a reproducible error?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a problem with `groovy > 2.4.7`.
I just filed an issue for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8156
Temporary solution use `groovy < 2.4.8` until bug is fixed.